# Redirection to Secured Server (https)

Tags: javascript, redirect

I don't have access to the .htaccess file, so I am using below JavaScript for redirection from http to https and append www.

```js
if(window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
  location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://www.");
}
```

The problem is that when a user enters http://www.example.com, it redirects to https://www.www.example.com.

Please help me resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
  location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://"); // <-- removed www.
}
```

Simply remove the `www.` to avoid duplicating it

Or even this as you only need to switch the beginning of the url:

```
if(window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
      location.href = location.href.replace("http", "https");
}
```

You should set your server to accept `www.example.com` OR just `example.com`, then it doesn't matter whether the user has added `www` or not